# Check a list of words and return found words from page source code with a unique list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests, python-re

I have looked through various other questions but none seem to fit the bill. So here goes

I have a list of words

```py
l = ['red','green','yellow','blue','orange']
```

I also have a source code of a webpage in another variable. I am using the requests lib

```py
import requests

url = 'https://google.com'
response = requests.get(url)
source = response.content
```

I then created a substring lookup function like so

```py
def find_all_substrings(string, sub):

    import re
    starts = [match.start() for match in re.finditer(re.escape(sub), string)]
    return starts
```

I now lookup the words using the following code where I am stuck

```py
for word in l:
    substrings = find_all_substrings(source, word)
    new = []
    for pos in substrings:
        ok = False
        if not ok:
            print(word + ";")
            if word not in new:
                new.append(word)
                print(new)
            page['words'] = new
```

My ideal output looks like the following

Found words - `['red', 'green']`

Comment: did you try BeautifulSoup parser ?

Comment: Hey @woblob, its not so much the parser but the logic. The function does find the word. Its the output of the list that either doubles up sometimes or sometimes shows up 10 times.

Comment: you dont change "ok" variable

Comment: "I am stuck" doesn't help. What error do you run into when you execute your code. Which line is causing the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is a list of words that are present, you can avoid most of the regex processing and just use

```
found_words = [word for word in target_words if word in page_content]
```

(I've renamed your `string` -> `page_content` and `l` -> `target_words`.)

If you need additional information or processing (e.g. the regexs / BeautifulSoup parser) and have a list of items which you need to deduplicate, you can just run it through a `set()` call. If you need a list instead of a set, or want to guarantee the order of found_words, just cast it again. Any of the following should work fine:

```
found_words = set(possibly_redundant_list_of_found_words)
found_words = list(set(possibly_redundant_list_of_found_words))
found_words = sorted(set(possibly_redundant_list_of_found_words))
```

If you've got some sort of data structure you're parsing (because BeautifulSoup & regex can provide supplemental information about position & context, and you might care about those), then just define a custom function `extract_word_from_struct()` which extracts the word from that structure, and call that inside a set comprehension:

```
possibly_redundant_list_of_found_words = [extract_word_from_struct(struct) for struct in possibly_redundant_list_of_findings]
found_words = set(word for word in possibly_redundant_list_of_found_words if word in target_words)
```

Comment: ahh! So simple yet I spent hours trying to debug as my list kept getting overwritten. Thank you kind stranger.